# Homestead "No input file specified " on Name.app

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I looked at a lot of the other issues but none of those answers were solving my issue.
I'm using Laravel Homestead, and I cannot connect to the .app when I set up the server.
When I initially installed homestead, no Code folder was created, so I put the files into the Code folder manually (and tried just changing the yaml file to not look for /Code/wavvve as well).
Looking for some guidance to see what I can try next, here is the current yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
 cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox 
mariadb: true


authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: C:\Users\Nick\Documents\GitHub\wavve
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/wavvve

sites:
- map: wavvve.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/wavvve/public

databases:
- homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
192.168.10.10
```

My current directories are the following:

```
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\GitHub\Homestead\Homestead
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\GitHub\wavve
```

on my VagrantBox my directories are as follows

```
/home/Code/wavvve
/home/wavvve
```

I manually made the Code folder to try to resolve the issue, when I first installed and set up everything, I have no code folder inside the directory.

I have tried starting with `vagrant up --provision` and I haven't had any success with it, and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: yaml files are finicky, so just two small things to verify. Did you use spaces instead of a tab for indenting? And when you say you started with vagrant up --provision, did you run vagrant halt prior? If not, try vagrant reload --provision

Comment: At the bottom of your yaml file there is a miss placed ip address. `192.168.10.10`. Try commenting it out